# Submit a table to nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to send a editable table to my nodejs server, but the response is "undefined". How can i fix this?

All my form's elements are parsed, except the table.

The server reports the following:

> DyanmicTable: undefined
>   ::1 - POST /creat_xml HTTP/1.1 200 - - 29.117 ms

Below is the HTML form with the table, and the server's code.

```html
<form id="msform" class="form" action="/creat_xml" method="POST">

  <table
    class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed  text-center"
    id="DyanmicTable" name="DyanmicTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">Repère</th>
      <th class="text-center">Quantité</th>
      <th class="text-center">Segments</th>
      <th class="text-center">Fixations latérales</th>
      <th class="text-center">Dalle à gauche</th>
      <th class="text-center">Commentaires</th>
      <th class="text-center">
        <button id="addNewRow" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Ajouter une
          ligne
        </button>

      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    $('#DyanmicTable').SetEditable({ $addButton: $('#addNewRow') });
  </script>
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button"
         value="Précédent"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button"/>

</form>
```

and my server:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(morgan('short'));

app.post('/creat_xml', (req, res) => {
  console.log('DyanmicTable: ' + req.body.DyanmicTable);
  res.json();
});

//localhost:8080
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('server lancé! ecoute du port 8080...');
});
```

Comment: There's no code there which would trigger an HTTP request of any kind. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @Quentin i just edited the post

Comment: The HTML is invalid, and you have no code that would translate the editable table into a form control.

Comment: the table is in the form, i'm using the "name" property (DynamicTable) like the other inputs (not in this code). i can get all the input values except the table which is **undifined**

Comment: There is no `name` attribute for `<table>` elements. Tables are not inputs. You should use [a validator](https://validator.nu/).

Comment: ** name="DyanmicTable"** is on the top of <table>  no?

Comment: You can write invalid HTML. Don't expect browsers to do anything useful with it though.

Comment: What Quentin was saying is that you can't pass invalid HTML. Using `name` attribute for a `table` is invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

Tables are not form elements, so they are ignored when a form is submitted.

The only elements that are sent with a `<form>` submit are:

- `<button`>
- `<fieldset>`
- `<input>`
- `<object>`
- `<output>`
- `<select>`
- `<textarea>`

If you want to submit contents of a table, and you don't want to write a custom submit function, include `<input>` elements inside your table cells and give each input a unique name:

```html
<tr>
  <td><input name="col1" /></td>
  <td><input name="col2" /></td>
  <td><input name="col3" /></td>
  <td><input name="col4" /></td>
  <td><input name="col5" /></td>
  <td><input name="col6" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi @Terrymorse thank you for your explanantions. the idea of converting cells in inputs don't work :( i'll try to find another way thank you for the answer

Comment: @SaifEjjilali Why won't `<td><input></td>` work? If you provide more detail than "don't work", there's a chance someone can offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

here's my html modified like you told me and the script i use to post the form

```
<script> 
$('#msform').submit( function(e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var col1 = $('#col1').val();
  var col2 = $('#col2').val();
  var col3 = $('#col3').val();
  var col4 = $('#col4').val();
  var col5 = $('#col5').val();
  var col6 = $('#col6').val();

  $.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: '/creat_xml',
data: {     
        col1,
        col2,
        col3,
        col4,
        col5,
        col6,     
},
success: (res)=>{
console.log(res);
}
}); 
});    
 </script>
```

Serverside my code get the form inputs:

```
app.post("/creat_xml", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Création formulaire en cours...")
   console.log("col1: " + req.body.col1)
   console.log("col2: " + req.body.col2)
   console.log("col3: " + req.body.col3)
   console.log("col4: " + req.body.col4)
   console.log("col5: " + req.body.col5)
   console.log("col6: " + req.body.col6)
  res.send()

})
```

The result is still undefined